# External static resources with Jetty

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I have the following Jetty config:

```
<webAppConfig>
   <defaultsDescriptor>${project.basedir}/configuration/webdefaults.xml</defaultsDescriptor>
   <contextPath>/app</contextPath>
   <baseResource implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.ResourceCollection">
      <resourcesAsCSV>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp,/external/dir,/another/dir</resourcesAsCSV>
   </baseResource>
</webAppConfig>
```

Now, both in my src/main/webapp and in /external/dir, I have a directory called static, and resources from both are accessible through URL /app/static just fine. Yet, in /another/dir, I have a directory that is called special-static and for some reason, resources in it are not accessible (or at least not using URL /app/special-static).

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The xml entry ...

```xml
<resourcesAsCSV>dir1,dir2,dir3</resourcesAsCSV>
```

Takes [C]omma [S]eparated [V]alues, use `","` not `";"` in your configuration.

Comment: Actually, it works with both. But anyway, switching to commas does not help, I've just tried it :( Also, I'll amend the question.

Answer (score 0):

What version do you use?

With version 8 or 9, I would do something like:

```
 <webAppConfig>
  ...
  <resourceBases>
   <resourceBase>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp</resourceBase>
   <resourceBase>/external/dir</resourceBase>
   <resourceBase>/another/dir</resourceBase>
  </resourceBases>
 </webAppConfig>
```

If you are using an outdated version (6 or 7), I encourage you to upgrade to the latest version 8.